# Mongo: how to select from id-array when id in array( not object array )

Tags: mongodb

```
{ members : [ ObjectId("one"), ObjectId("two") ]}
```

I want select "one" Whether in members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind: '$members'}, {$match: {members: ObjectId("one")}}])
```

In this case you will get all of documents which has member one. You can use a first $match criteria or/and $limit:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match: {<expr>}}, {$unwind: '$members'}, {$match: {members: ObjectId("one")}}, {$limit: 1}])
```

You will have result array with objects, but it's simple to use. But I think this is dirty hack :)